# "Volume control applet" change source in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

i have a litle problem and can't find the solution.

The volume applet on Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity controlls 4 channels in the audio mixer:

- Master (increase or decrease)
- Speaker (2 states: min if I down or max if I up the volume)
- PCM (the same like speaker)
- Front (the same like speaker)

I want to change this behaivor and allow only to regulate the Master channel.

how can I change this setting ?

Comment: try [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, AskUbuntu should be your target, but I think [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/243572) contains an aswer for your problem (although the question was to another problem)

Comment: I used your solution partially. I create that 2 shortcuts in the keyboard setting, so the Compiz is not required. Thanks ;)